# Разделить строку на подстроки регулярным выражением

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка следующего формата: `"aaAABBCeeff123FE"`, необходимо сгруппировать пары. Т.е результат будет такой: `"aa", "AA", "BB", "ee", "ff", "FE"`.

Я написал следующий код:

```
Regex.Matches("aaAABBCeeff123FE", @"([a-z]|[A-Z]){2}");
```

Он работает, но не совсем так, как нужно. Он объединяет так же заглавные и строчные буквы, а мне нужно разделение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```cs
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"\p{Lu}{2}|\p{Ll}{2}")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value);
```

См. [пример работы выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cp%7BLu%7D%7B2%7D%7C%5Cp%7BLl%7D%7B2%7D&i=aaAABBCeeff123FE):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Подробности**:

- `\p{Lu}{2}` - две заглавных буквы
- `|` - или
- `\p{Ll}{2}` - две строчных буквы.

Если вдруг потребуется разбить строку на пересекающиеся (overlapping) подстроки, используйте

```cs
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?=(\p{Lu}{2}|\p{Ll}{2}))")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```

См. [пример работы этого выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3D%28%5Cp%7BLu%7D%7B2%7D%7C%5Cp%7BLl%7D%7B2%7D%29%29&i=aaaAAAACB).